# UITextField ignoring constraints and shifting text offscreen

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created a static table view in Storyboard with one cell that contains a UITextField for text entry. The text field has constraints to bind it to the cell for top, bottom, trailing, and leading so that it will have the right width on all resolutions.

In viewDidLoad, I enter some placeholder text for an empty state.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *placeholderString = 
[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] 
initWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"Note", @"")];
[placeholderString beginEditing];
[placeholderString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value: 
[PulseColor tableViewEmptyCellBackgroundColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, 
placeholderString.length)];
[placeholderString endEditing];

self.txtNote.attributedPlaceholder = placeholderString;
self.txtNote.delegate = self;
```

The problem is that rather that sticking to the constraints, the width of the UITextField shrinks to the size of the placeholder text. As I type and the message reaches the end of the smaller text field, the text expands to the left and disappears before expanding to the right. (If I had the reputation, I'd post images)

Is there a setting that I am missing or some other way that will either cause the UITextField to keep its width across the cell, or cause the text to not disappear to the left as it reaches the initial length?

Comment: Are you getting any conflicting / failing constraint warnings?

Comment: check debugger to see if break constraint

Comment: attaching interface builder and simulator screenshots will be helpful to propose solution.